# VS Code Does Not Recognize Site Packages in Virtual Env With Homebrew Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv, homebrew

I am using VS Code and I am selecting the python interpreter (via. CMD + Shift + P) from within my virtual environment folder (`~/Python_Envs/dev/bin/python`), created via `python -m venv Python_Envs/dev`. That is a symbolic link to the python from Homebrew in Cellar. But the packages in `~/Python_Envs/dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages` are not picked up. Import statements show errors/underlines.

From terminal (on Mac), if I activate this virtual environment everything works, just not in VS Code when I select the interpreter. Not sure what is going on and other posts don't seem to address the issue. Before I used conda environments which seemed to work fine (without homebrew python). I am sure I am missing something obvious.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Could it be that VS Code is picking up the site-packages under the python in Homebrew?

Comment: What is the error content?